# Model-view-viemodel pattern

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, design-patterns, mvvm

I have two related entities in domain layer(Entity Framework):
TaxGroup
TaxSubGroup
TaxGroup entities belongs to TaxGroup entities(one to many relationship). Where i must imlement this relationship(datamodel or viewmodel)?

EDIT

What about this datamodel's implementation?

```
public class TaxGroupDataModel : DataModel
{
    private readonly TaxGroup _taxGroup;
    private readonly IEnumerable<TaxSubGroup> _taxSubGroups;

    public TaxGroupDataModel(TaxGroup taxGroup)
    {
        if (taxGroup == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("taxGroup"); }


        _taxGroup = taxGroup;
        _taxSubGroups = taxGroup.SubGroups;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TaxSubGroup> TaxSubGroups { get { return _taxSubGroups; } }

    public TaxGroup TaxGroup { get { return _taxGroup; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relationships are part of the data, so they should be part of the `Model` layer

The `ViewModel` is responsible for exposing data to the View, and for any business logic that would occur such as getting/saving data, running commands, etc